# Google App Engine Java session latency price

Tags: java, google-app-engine, servlets

We need to enable java servlet sessions support for one Google App Engine project, but session will be used only in one servlet (small isolated part of application).

Would we get some increased latency impact (because of session memcache/datastore object) in other servlets although session object would not be used in any other servlets?

Is there a way to disable sessions support for some servlets ?

Comment: Have you actually measured to determine if this is the case? I find it very difficult to believe it would be noticeable.

Comment: I could live with one read and 1:10-100 write, but not with one write extra for every request.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no way to enable sessions on a per servlet basis.

Also sessions consume a read from memcache and a write to datastore for every request. So this can get costly.

Additionally if your client does not handle cookies (usually devices via REST), then every request will create a new session entity in datastore. And this will grow indefinitely.

The solution is to roll your own sessions - create servlet filter that gets/sets cookies only for certain path/servlet.

Comment: Wait, why write to datastore for every request? I understand read from memcache and ev. read from datastore.

Comment: To update the expiry time. Enable sessions and look for `_ah_session` entities in your datastore.